# Installation of file on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, compiling

I just tried to install this file here on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

When I click on it ubuntu opens a dialogue to install `pypar2` which I did and then the file is opened with `pypar2` it looks like this:

[image]

But afterwards I can't execute msmc on the desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Those are pre-compiled files. There's nothing more to install, looking at the README. You run them. First, make the file executable:

```
$ chmod +x msmc_linux_64bit
```

Then run it:

```
$ ./msmc_linux_64bit 
Usage: msmc [options] <datafiles>
  Options:
    -i, --maxIterations=<size_t> : number of EM-iterations [default=20]
    -o, --outFilePrefix=<string> : file prefix to use for all output files
    -r, --rhoOverMu=<double>: ratio of recombination rate over mutation rate. Default=0.25.
    -t, --nrThreads=<size_t> : nr of threads to use (defaults to nr of CPUs)
    -p, --timeSegmentPattern=<string> : pattern of fixed time segments [default=10*1+15*2]
    -P, --subpopLabels=<string> comma-separated subpopulation labels (assume one single population by default, with 
          number of haplotypes inferred from first input file). For cross-population analysis with 4 haplotypes, 2 
          coming from each subpopulation, set this to 0,0,1,1
    -R, --fixedRecombination : keep recombination rate fixed [recommended, but not set by default]
    -I, --indices: indices (comma-separated) of alleles in the data file to run over
    -s, --skipAmbiguous: skip sites with ambiguous phasing. Recommended for gene flow analysis
    -h, --help: show this message
```